# Positive synonym for "smirk" — to smile in a proud, self-satisfied way

Tags: single-word-requests

How to say someone smiles out of pride and affirmation?

Lee was sitting at the table, and heard a story about someone else convincing a denier of the indubitable truth of Lee's own theory.

> Lee leant back and ____.

Lee has the attitude "I'm glad you see"

How can you say someone smiles, self-contentedly

Out of smugness or pride, very happy to have themselves affirmed by something.

Comment: Sounds like he [grinned](https://www.macmillandictionaryblog.com/why-do-we-grin-like-a-cheshire-cat).

Comment: @YosefBaskin I imagine a smile that doesn't show the teeth and also has the eyes quite squinted or even closed

Comment: Got it now. Positive - not quite smirking - self-satisfied - smiling - pride and affirmation - glad attitude - self-contented - smug - very happy - affirmed - not grinning - doesn't show teeth - squinted eyes.

Answer (score 3):

You might try the word "beam." One beams with pride.

Comment: This does not necessarily involve a smile, but it does convey the rest of the meaning very well.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean.  I've never heard "beam" used to convey an expression that does not involve a smile.

Comment: Oh, I think Joachim's comment pertains to "bask" and he accidentally wrote it in the wrong place.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like [the cat that ate the canary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+cat+that+ate+the+canary)

> Someone who is smugly pleased or self-satisfied.
>
> After her promotion, Janet spent the rest of the day looking like the cat that ate the canary.
>
> Look at those kids with their ice creams—the cats that ate the
> canaries!

the cat that ate the canary. (n.d.) Farlex Dictionary of Idioms. (2015). Retrieved January 28 2021 from https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+cat+that+ate+the+canary

Answer (score 2):

As well as Phil Sweet's nice answer, **bask** seems to fit in the context.

> To take great pleasure or satisfaction:

*“an opportunity to bask in the genteel applause of the faithful” (Paul A. Witteman).*

[American Heritage Dictionary]

Therefore, you could say—

*Lee leant back and basked in the affirmation of his theory.*